# How do I Get My HeightAnchor Working Properly?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, gradient, autolayout

In my MainVC, I'm trying to constrain an UIView to the top, left, right and have a height of 80. Right now, my view is full screen. How would I fix my code to be able to have the right size?

// Variables
    var topViewCons : [NSLayoutConstraint] = []

```
// Constants
let topGradient = RadialGradientLayer()
let topMainView = UIView()
// MainVC Top View Constraints
topMainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
topGradient.frame = view.bounds
topMainView.layer.addSublayer(topGradient)
self.view.addSubview(topMainView)

let topConstraint = topMainView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor)
let leftConstraint = topMainView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor)
let rightConstraint = topMainView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor)
let topViewHeight = topMainView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([topConstraint, leftConstraint, rightConstraint, topViewHeight])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not full screen , the gradient is

```
topGradient.frame = view.bounds  // here you make it's frame to screen bounds 
topMainView.layer.addSublayer(topGradient)
```

so you need to set

```
topMainView.clipsToBounds = true
```

**OR**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
  super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
  topGradient.frame = topMainView.bounds
}
```

---

Also you can do this directly without lets

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      topMainView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
      topMainView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
      topMainView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
      topMainView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80)
])
```

Comment: Thanks!! ClipToBounds worked perfectly!! Could I even set constraints in an ext. then that way my VCs are cleaner?

Comment: yes you can create an extension function  to **UIViewController** and pass the anchor , child and parent view ,and set all other stuff inside it

Comment: Sweet! This is my first app using auto layout programmatically. So thanks for helping me. :)